# Auto-insert code from sms with on-screen keyboard in ios app, if form is implemented with multiple instances?

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

The application is angular, ionic, cordova.
Has anyone encountered this: the code entry form from sms is implemented with four instances.

---

If you open the app in the safari browser, then at the code entry stage ios pulls up the code from the sms and offers to paste it by pressing the "From Messages" button on the keyboard and the code itself. In this case, the code is inserted correctly.

But all the same in the assembled application for ios works a little differently. When pasting the code from the onscreen keyboard the whole code tries to be pasted only into the first instance, which has the maximum length of 1. Because of this only the first digit of the code in the first instance is pasted, while the rest remain empty. At the same time, if you manually select, copy and paste the code when the focus is on the first intu, then all the intuits are filled correctly. Most likely in the assembled application and in the Safari browser auto-paste code from the on-screen keyboard works differently and some other event is called in the application.

This theory was tested by assembling an ios app for the test, where the code entry system is implemented with one instance rather than 4. In this case, code insertion from the on-screen keyboard worked.

Is there any solution to auto-insert code from sms with on-screen keyboard in ios app, if form is implemented with several instances?

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let code of form.controls | keyvalue; index as i">
            <app-input [formControlName]="code.key"
                       #codes
                       color="dark"
                       class="code-input"
                       size="medium"
                       [mask]="'9'"
                       state="error"
                       [showErrorElement]="false"
                       [state]="isError ? 'error' : null"
                       [inputForCode]="true"
                       [enterkeyhint]="'go'"
                       [inputmode]="'numeric'"
                       [addClass]="'input-text'"
                       [maxlength]="1"
                       [dontShowDisabled]="true"
                       autocomplete="one-time-code"
                       (keyupEvent)="nextCode($event, i)"
                       (clickEvent)="select(i)"
                       (paste)="paste($event)"
                       (input)="paste($event)"
            ></app-input>
</ng-container>
```